# preg_match to find two digit numbers with above 14

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am using the below code to identify the text or nothing followed by 2 or 3 digit numbers

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]{2,3}$/",trim($textMessage),$result)
```

It works fine. But I need to find the digit from above 14 only. But the above code matches from 10 itself.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just check it afterwards? Trying to do everything with regular expressions, if possible (in this case, it is), is pointless when you could use that time doing more useful things.

Comment: it is not advised to do this with regex, this bad logic might encourage you to find ways if a number is prime or not using regex :-/

Answer (score 3):

Regex shouldn't really be used for comparisons like this - it's more for pattern matching. So, keep your regex the way it is and test `$result`:

```
<?php

$textMessage = '123';
preg_match("/^[0-9]{2,3}$/",trim($textMessage),$result);
print_r($result);


if($result[0] > 14)
{
   // do something here
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy.  you switch your number part from

```
[0-9]{2,3}
```

to this:

```
(1[5-9])|([2-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9]{2})
```

Comment: It works, but I can't help thinking regular expressions aren't the right tool for this.

Comment: I know it's not the right tool for this.  I was hoping that @Coder would see that after seeing what kind of regexp you'd need to construct for it, but *shrug* if he's happy with it..

Comment: You probably want `[1-9][0-9]{2}`, not `{2,3}`. You can also remove the 3 capturing groups, but don't forget the `^`...`$` anchors: `^(1[5-9]|[2-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2})$`